# Difference between Windows edition and OS name

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

When running via Powershell the comlets, `Get-ComputerInfo | Select WindowsEditionId, OsName` I get the following result:

```ps
PS C:\> Get-ComputerInfo | Select WindowsEditionId, OsName

WindowsEditionId OsName
---------------- ------
Professional     Microsoft Windows 10 Business
```

I would have assumed that Windows 10 Business would have been shown for both as we have a subscription to Microsoft 365. The version originally installed is/was Windows 10 Pro Looking at the Activation settings, "Microsoft Windows 10 Business" is shown. So, why isn't the same result shown?

[image: Windows 10 - Settings - Activation]

Comment: I don't really have the answer to your question, but I found a site where most of the Windows 10 EditionIds are documented: https://betawiki.net/wiki/User:Cvolton/user/List_of_Windows_10_editions Windows 10 Business is not on there, nor can I find anything in Google about it. What I do know is that Microsoft likes to rename stuff. What Version of Windows 10 are you running? Could it be that Windows 10 Pro is called Windows 10 Business in the newest Version? Since it has the same EditionId, it almost has to be the same.

Comment: @SimonS Please see edit.

Comment: what does `get-ciminstance win32_operatingsystem | select Caption, Version` return?

Comment: @SimonS It returns Microsoft Windows 10 Business 10.0.19043

Comment: Windows 10 Business is being detected due to your subscription to Microsoft 365 Business.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound the question is why is the WindowsEditionId and OsName showing different version?

Comment: [Because of your subscription to Microsoft 365 Business.](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2034691-what-is-windows-10-business). The Windows edition you have is still Professional or simply due to the fact the key isn’t modified.